Not able to open job object using OpenJobObjectA
I am writing a program that will open a job object present in \BaseNamedObjects namespace using OpenJobObjectA. Below is snippet of code:
 hJob = OpenJobObjectA(JOB_OBJECT_QUERY, FALSE, "\\BaseNamedObjects\\SAC10680");
 if (hJob == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open job object. Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
     return 1;
 }

Now, even though the job object is present(which I verify using winobj) I am not able to open the object. And getting below error:
Failed to open job object. Error code: 161

I know error 161 means path is invalid. But that's not true!!
The code should open the job object.

path is really invalid for this api. this is not win32 path, but nt path. this path is ok for NtOpenJobObjectapi. for OpenJobObject you need Global\\SAC10680

According to the Doc:OpenJobObjectA function
The name can have a "Global" or "Local" prefix to explicitly open the object in the global or session namespace. The remainder of the name can contain any character except the backslash character ().
The driver creates a named event object in the global \BaseNamedObjects object directory. To access a kernel-mode event from user-mode, use the name Global\\Xxx.
I agree with RbMm, you should try to use Global\\SAC10680.

Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this is not working.

Is the error code still 161?

yes, it's the same.

Have you removed the initial "/"？
hJob = OpenJobObjectA(JOB_OBJECT_QUERY, FALSE, "Global\SAC10680");

Oh! my bad. I was using \Global. But now after removing \ it is working. Thanks
